# Jetbrains Plugin SDK: Add action to toolbar for all Jetbrains IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, toolbar, intellij-plugin, jetbrains-rider

I'm developing a plugin for Jetbrains IDEs, which includes an action item that I want to include in the main toolbar at the top. (I'm not super familiar with Jetbrains so forgive me for my lack of correct terminology).

I have been able to include the action in the toolbar for IDEA by specifying the `group-id` as `ToolBarRunGroup` (see snippet below). This was fine up until one of our users (who uses Ride) said that the action was not there for them.

```
// plugin.xml

<idea-plugin require-restart="false">
    // ...
    <actions>
        <action id="<action ID>"
                class="<action class>"
                text="<action text>"
                description="<action description>"
                icon="<path/to/action/icon>">
            <add-to-group group-id="ToolBarRunGroup" anchor="first"/>
        </action>
    </actions>
    // ...
</idea-plugin>
```

I installed Ride to try this out and the action is indeed missing, though it can be added via the "Customize Toolbar..." dialogue.

The following image shows the toolbar in Ride where I want the action to show up. Ideally it would be placed to the left of the "Build Solution" icon.

[image]

Ideally, I would like the action to be included in the toolbar for all Jetbrains IDEs. I have tried looking in the "Internal Actions -> UI inspector" to find a common `group-id` but it seems that each IDE uses slightly different ones.

Is there another way I can ensure the action is included in the toolbar for all IDEs?

Comment: If you still haven't gotten an answer here, you could try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html#problems-with-code-support-issues which has more people involved knowing the JetBrains plugin development.

Answer (score 0):

`<add-to-group group-id="NavBarToolBar" anchor="first"/>` should add your action to your ToolBar. If it doesn't come there, try deleting your build folder and rebuilding the plugin.